# ARC impressions

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

It's about an year since Apple introduced ARC. I personally haven't tried it yet - mostly because I fill nice with classical retain/release scheme. And ARC seems to me like yet another "Objective-C GC bubble" – technology that promises to make memory management easier, but instead just makes the problem more complicated, by moving the control from the programmer and replacing the old well-known and clean rules with some others implicit ones.

I'm just wondering, what impressions do the developers have, who had a chance to use it in real-world production applications? Is it a relief or a big disappointment?

Thanks in advance,
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly never really minded doing memory management manually. That being said, I love ARC for a few reasons:

1. Time saver
2. Code reducer
3. **ZEROING WEAK REFERENCES!!!** I love blocks and they are becoming more and more popular. Zeroing weak references are huge for blocks. To achieve zeroing weak references without using ARC you need to use something like [MAZeroingWeakRef](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/introducing-mazeroingweakref.html), which is a suitable but less ideal solution.

It may seem like ARC wouldn't save much time or reduce the amount of code you have to write too drastically, but in my opinion it actually makes a bigger difference than you think. I was skeptical at first but I would never start a new project without ARC at this point.

Comment: could you please give a usage pattern for zeroing weak references with blocks?

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy it. I think it's great.

It was a little weird to get used to at first, but I would never go back (I don't think). I can't think of one instance where I feel ARC impeded me, and indeed I think it is a HUGE relief to not have to worry anymore about obscure dangling pointers or memory management rules :)

Answer (score 0):

I may sound noobish, but ARC made things quite more intuitive during programming. I moved in from Visual C# and on to Xcode, and the change wasn't that drastic, since c# has had memory management automated for a while now. I guess it is more of a personal preference thing.